# Details of GNU Common Lisp's (type-of)

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, clisp, gnu-common-lisp

If at the REPL I enter:

```
(type-of (make-array 5))
```

then I get the response:

```
(SIMPLE-VECTOR 5)
```

Fair enough.  So if at the REPL I enter:

```
(type-of (make-array (list 5 3 2)))
```

then I get the response:

```
(SIMPLE-ARRAY T (5 3 2))
```

I have two questions.

1. What is the `T` telling me here?  If it had been `NIL` instead, what would that have told me?
2. Where could I have found this answer on my own?  I failed to find the answer in (for example) the Lisp HyperSpec.

Comment: GNU Common Lisp (short GCL) and GNU CLISP are two different implementations of Common Lisp. You don't need to tag general questions with all kinds of implementation names.

Comment: Ooo.  Thank you.  Had no idea.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(SIMPLE-ARRAY T (5 3 2))` is a simple array of three dimensions. `T` says that it is a general array which can contain any element type. `T` is the most general type.

The hyperspec documents the type SIMPLE-ARRAY here:

http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/t_smp_ar.htm

Comment: Ooo.  Thanks!  Your link was tough sledding for me, but ultimately useful!  I figured out, for example, that (type-of (make-array 5 :element-type (integer 0 255))) yields (SIMPLE-ARRAY (UNSIGNED-BYTE 8) (5)).

Answer (score 1):

1) If the T had been NIL, you would have a three-dimensional array, specialised in not storing data (no element has the type NIL; I believe all types are a super-type of NIL).